# Access the value of an xml tag via xsl and put this value into an XSL attribute

Tags: xml, jquery-mobile, xslt, tags

I have an XML file with the tag

```
<min>0</min>
```

and I am writing an XSL file, which should extract the "0" out of this tag and put it into a jQuery mobile slider like that:

```
<input type="range" name="slider-7" id="slider-7" value="5" min="THE ZERO I NEED" etc.../>
```

xsl:value-of select="" doesn't seem to do the job as it extracts the value of an attribute, not of a tag and I can't write min=xsl:value-of...

So how can I do this extraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an AVT ([attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates)) with the XPath to the value you need.

For example, if `min` is a child of the current context, you could do:

```
<input min="{min}"/>
```

If `min` *is* the current context, just use `.`:

```
<input min="{.}"/>
```